# Can't click on the option select2

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I try using select2 jquery, it can display the data from database after I type in the input and scroll up down the data, but I can't click on the data displayed. I don't know what's wrong on it, and I don't know how to fix it.

here's my view

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <select class="searching form-control" style="width:500px" name="searching"></select>
  </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.searching').select2({
    placeholder: '--- Select Company ---',
    ajax: {
      url: '<?php echo base_url('Company2/select2');?>',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true

    }
  });
```

Here's my controller

```
public function select2(){
$json = [];


$this->load->database();

if(!empty($this->input->get("q"))){
  $this->db->like('Name', $this->input->get("q"));
  $query = $this->db->select('Name as text')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get("dbo.Company");
  $json = $query->result();
}


echo json_encode($json);
 }
```

Comment: you're not providing any options...

Comment: I don't know any option to fix it, cause I think everthing is right,  but it still can't click on the option

Comment: I mean in your html.  you have a select box, and are echoing values into it, but they are not in there as "options"   Think back to html forms <select name="bla"><option value="val1">  </select> etc

Comment: It still can't, after I adding <option></option> on it. the option come from database when I type some characters it will display the name of company contain that character

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or codesandbox version for your code?

Comment: show your html part. z-index might solve your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select2` expect option value field and you aren't passing it.

Result parameter should be like as follows.

`"results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
]`

You need to altere here. `$this->db->select('Name as id, Name as text')`